# Maui Blazor Developer F12

Tags: blazor, developer-tools, maui

Is it possible to turn off the developer F12 in the release version Maui Blazor application?
I'm currently evaluating Maui Blazor, and I have a real concern with the F12 being active in the release version. I'm in and industry that deals with narcotics and tabaco and someone having the ability to poke around in the UI and also look at the network communication is of a real concern to me.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way of disabling the developer tools. It shouldn't be any more of a concern than running it in a web browser, also because that is essentially what it's doing.

If that's not what you want, you will want to look into other ways to develop your app. However, one can still inspect the network traffic and reverse engineer that way if they want.

The real solution here is to make sure that your ways of communication are secure. What that looks like exactly is heavily dependant on what you app looks like and the architecture of both your app and backend looks like etc, to it's hard to comment on that.

Answer (score 0):

Add a js file to wwwroot/js in your app
Add the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(document).keydown(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 123) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

}

Comment for further discussion.

Comment: Trying to disable it will hardly prevent hackers to keep messing with the UI or take a look at the code on their computer.The best way of securing data is to control it from a server where the user don't have direct access.